# Multiple underbrackets for sequence

Tags: underbrace

I wonder how to display the following sequence.

[image]

What I tried: (I am not to concered about about the type of brackets (curly, round, ...) but I would really like to have all of them in my equation...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  1
  \underbrace{
    \underbrace{,}_{6} 
    7
    \underbrace{,}_{10}
  }_{4}
  17
  \underbrace{
    \underbrace{,}_{14}
    31
    \underbrace{,}_{18}
  }_{4}
  49
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Formula parsed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\ubf{\kern-2\tabcolsep\upbracefill\kern-2\tabcolsep}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
    1&&7&&17&&31&&49\\[-3pt]
     & \ubf&&\ubf&&\ubf&&\ubf\\
     & 6&&10&&14&&18\\[-3pt]
     &  &\ubf&&\ubf&&\ubf\\
     &  &4&&4&&4
  \end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could put `,` between the `&&`  of the first line if you want (but I didn't like them:-)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for :)